# Extracting email from a specific sender from Outlook in Python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I'm trying to develop some code that will extract email from my outlook account from a specific sender, and print that email in a command session for me. I am using the win32 library, and have already got some code to read email from my outlook account, which is shown below:

```
import win32com.client

win32com

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

However, this code only extracts the last email received. For what I want to do, I need to search for email from a specific sender, and print the body of that email. I'm sure there must be a simple enough module to do this, but i am unable to find out what module exists to allow me to do this. Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.